# Bootstrap Datepicker not loading any css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am trying to create a bootstrap datepicker in my MVC application

The data picker is loading and creating but there is no style being attached to the control whatsoever.

I have made sure to include the datepicker3.css and the bootstrap-datepicker.js files and they are loading with a status code of 200 so I don't think these are the issue.

**HTML for the control**

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepickers">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.datepickers').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Screen shot of how the control looks on the screen[image: Sample]

It may also be worth noting that the date picker is also ignoring the format and using `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Could you please create a snippet/fiddle ([mcve]) in which we could observe/inspect the issue?

Comment: Have you added the bootstrap datepicker CSS file before the script file?

Comment: A full code snippet would be perfect to start with. What are you getting on your console ?

Comment: nothing at all appears on the console and I have added the CSS file at the top of the page and the script at the bottom of the page. Unfortunately I am unable to paste the full page due to some of the information contained on the page

Comment: what is the sequence of imported CSS files ?

Comment: I think your css is not being picked up just like your datepicker.js